# jQuery: iPhone numeric keypad not closing in a native app

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone

There are three radio buttons being displayed in a modal window with a close icon in the header.

1. First radio button is just a standard radio button option with a
   label.
2. Second radio button has an input text field which accepts only numbers
3. Third radio button also has another input text field which also accepts only numbers.

Issue: When this modal window is triggered and if the user taps on 2nd or 3rd radio button, the numeric keypad comes automatically. But, if the user doesn't enter any value and simply chooses to close the modal window by tapping on the close icon in the header of modal, the numeric keypad isn't closing along with modal window.

If the user taps on 2nd or 3rd radio buttons and then again taps on the first radio button before closing the modal, then the numeric keypad hides as expected.

Any suggestions on how to debug this issue will be helpful.

Comment: Which mobile web browser on which mobile device?

Comment: it is actually a native app in iPhone 6s (can be simulated in Safari browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A snippet of the actual HTML/JS would help, but at a guess I'd look at the last input in the control still having focus when you hide the modal dialog.

Make sure that the close icon on the modal is a `<button>` rather than just an image with a click event - this will ensure that the focus switched correctly.